# Tkinter checkbutton - text won't show up

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, checkbox, tkinter-macos

When I try to use a checkbutton it works fine but the text won't appear. I can't understand why. Below is my code

```
from tkinter import *
a = Tk()
var1 = IntVar()
Checkbutton(a, text="checkbutton", variable=var1, fg='blue').grid(row=0,sticky=W)
a.mainloop()
```

The checkbox appears but the text alongside does not

[image: This is what shows when I run it]

Comment: It's a MACOS issue, use `ttk.Checkbutton` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using themed tk (ttk) checkbutton widget:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

a = tk.Tk()

var1 = tk.IntVar()

check_btn = ttk.Checkbutton(a, text="checkbutton", variable=var1)
check_btn.grid(row=1,sticky='w')

# set foreground color to blue
check_btn_style = ttk.Style()
check_btn_style.configure('TCheckbutton', foreground='blue')

a.mainloop()
```